# I read from remote server some ugly letters

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fonts, vuejs2

In Laravel 5.8 / vuejs 2.6 I make search from remote server and outputting readed data I see some ugly symbols :
https://prnt.sc/p2nb2w

I suppose these(or part of them) are some arabic letters. I read the data with curl, having headers :

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));
```

On my site I use utf-8 and Cera-GR fonts.

Dumping readed data for printscreen with examples above I see in kate editor next text pieces:

```
    [Description] =>  Moroccan Travel lover living in Paris/Dubai Dubai

    [FullName] => ☕️pdl - Est. 2018 ☕️

            [Description] => Latin American Restaurant
Pisco Bar& Lounge 
Members' Club✨
+971(0)43169600 ☎️ reservations@coyarestaurant.ae
```

I am not sure what can I do here? What kind of symbols are there ? Change the fonts or clear some symbols?
If just clear them, by which rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of them from the string in Javascript, if that's what you'd like to achieve. Run them through this:

```
removeIllegalCharacters(string) {
    string.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim()
}
```

This will retain your spaces, but `.trim()` will ensure you don't have any leading or trailing spaces on the string.